# Can't find my bean in JBoss esb server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, esb

I have jbossesb-server-4.11 and eclipse-jee-juno.
I want to create some simple EJB application, deploy it on server and call some method from client. Everything seems to be clear.
I have found a simple Hello world application here: https://sites.google.com/a/thedevinfo.com/thedevinfo/Home/jboss/jboss-application-server/ejb3-session-bean-tutorial-using-jboss-and-eclipse.
I did all the same, I also tried to download this example from this site but it does not work for me.
I created JBoss server in Eclipse, then I run my ejb application on this server, then I tryied to get my bean this way:

```
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(props);         
MyBeanRemote bean = (MyBeanRemote) ctx.lookup("MyBean/remote");
```

But i have the following error: "javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: MyBean not bound".
Here is my simple code in ejb project:

```
@Remote
public interface MyBeanRemote extends IMyBean{}
@Local
public interface MyBeanLocal extends IMyBean {}
@Stateless  
public class MyBean implements MyBeanLocal, MyBeanRemote {
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");         
    }
}
```

Please advice me where I am wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like standalone `jbossesb-server` is very narrowly specialized product. It provides ESB-specific functionality but lacks EJB support.
Your test app deploys and runs fine on vanilla `JBossAS 4.2.3.GA` though (AS 4.2.3 is the foundation for `jbossesb-server-4.11` I think).

If ESB is a must for you, I recommend installing JBoss ESB as an extension for plain `JBoss 4.2.3.GA` or maybe newer 5.x, 6.x series (AFAIK 7.x is not supported yet). In order to do so you need to download `jboss-4.2.3.GA` and `jbossesb-4.11.zip` instead of jbossesb-**server**-4.11.zip. Then you need to follow [this](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossesb/docs/4.11/manuals/html/Getting_Started_Guide/index.html#sect-installing_to_as) instructions.
Pay attention there are two editions of `JBossAS 4.2.3`:

- `jboss-4.2.3.GA.zip` - for JDK5
- `jboss-4.2.3.GA-jdk6.zip` - for JDK6+

the same is true for 5.x series (6.x and 7.x require JDK6+).

The other option is using full commercial SOA solution: RedHat's `SOA Platform`. It's not cheap though.